# Should I use UITableView section header or static UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that is populated with dynamic data (search result).

What I now want to do is to have a non-floating section header or a static cell that displays what filter is being used on the search result, *e.g.* "**most recent**"

Should I use `UITableView` section header or static `UITableViewCell` to display the filter text? Or even just drop a `UIView` inside the `TableView`

Comment: It depends: if you want full control over the UI use a cell. If a simple title is enough then use the section header.

Comment: @Darko You have full control over the UI if you use a header section view. You don't need a cell for that.

Comment: @rmaddy do you mean by using a xib?

Comment: No. By implementing the appropriate table view delegate method.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah, yes, I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David's answer is correct. Also, the three options you are thinking of, the third one does not make sense. 
This is because a view inside table view is same as using section header with a custom view.

I would suggest you make a custom view, that you return in the tableview delegate method: `tableview: viewForHeader:`. 
If you use a plain tableview, this section header is affixed to view at the top, until that section gets over.(I guess that is what you are asking for.)

Comment: Right now I have just placed a UIView containing a label inside my tableview. I cant set any constraints only set the height using storyboards size inspector. Anyhow, everything works as I want but is there any reason not to use this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the title to "float" ie, stay at the top of the screen instead of scrolling offscreen, then use a section header.

If you don't want it to float, i.e., you want it to scroll offscreen with the rest of the table, use either a static cell or a tableViewHeader view.

Comment: Cant you just toggle this behaviour by setting the tableview to .Grouped? floating/none floating